# Backpropagation of convolutional neural network - confusion

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, cnn, backpropagation, mathematics

I've already seen many articles about this topic and [Backpropagation In Convolutional Neural Networks by Jefkine](http://www.jefkine.com/general/2016/09/05/backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks/) seems to be the best. Although, as author said,

> For the purposes of simplicity we shall use the case where the input image is grayscale i.e single channel C = 1.

Also, he uses stride = 1 and assumes only 1 filter, for the same purpose.

These are the final equations for backpropagation (taken from the article):

[image: Equations]

The autor's notation explained:

[image: Notation]

I figured out how to do the forward pass with stride, depth and more filters, but couldn't do the same with the backpropagation. Do you know where to put the 3rd dimension, stride and filters number in those equations?

Also, how to backpropagate the bias (assuming there's 1 bias per filter)?

Let me know if something is unclear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are conversant with calculus simply write down the equation for a layer and try to backpropagate, see which variables are affecting the output, try to differentiate w.r.t them, use relu for simplicity, this will require quite a long answer to be answered nicely,

Comment: @DuttaA The point is I am not, I think I'll mess something up, the indices etc. Could you do that? The final equations would be sufficient, I don't need to know all the calculus process.

Comment: Can't help you, I am not familiar with latex and I implemented it only once, it's quite cumbersome

Comment: https://becominghuman.ai/back-propagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks-intuition-and-code-714ef1c38199

Comment: https://medium.com/@2017csm1006/forward-and-backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-network-4dfa96d7b37e

Comment: http://www.jefkine.com/general/2016/09/05/backpropagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks/

Comment: I've already read those articles, the jefkine's one is the best imho, as he provides all the equations, whereas the rest don't. Couldn't you do that on a paper/in programs like paint?

Comment: This is the best i can help, i am really really unfamiliar with math notations and will only confuse you more, only 1 hint is if you get how to find derivative of a single layer try to think how you can backpropagate the error to previous layers by multiplyimg the previous layers derivative w.r.t input s and not weights

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I am not able to calculate the derivatives etc, as there's a lot of it, and I'd surely mess something up, then try to implement the wrong equations. I'm not sure what do you mean by being unfamiliar with math notations. There's also an online latex equation editor. Shall I post this question on math.stackexchange so people who are good in calculus could help?

Comment: Nope this isn't really a math question I think you either have to watch implementation codes and get it or maybe utube videos, or use a predefined library

Comment: I think it actually is, it could be formed in a "math way", because it's matter of the calculus

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequently asked question (see [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118631/cnn-back-propagation-on-a-3d-image), [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-derive-back-propagation-from-the-second-convolution-layer), [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/deeplearning/comments/ndmoau/convolutional_layer_multichannel_backpropagation/)). I
must admit that I haven't fully understood the generalized Brackprop of convolution
on 3D volumes, especially when using the chain of calculus without using
computational graphs. But I will give it a try.

I will use mostly the notation of the DL book (scalar $a$, matrix
$\boldsymbol{M}$, $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{M}}$ etc.)
and for some quantities the notation of Nielsen's book, e.g., $\delta^l_{...}$
for the neuron error at layer $l$ and I will consider the convolutional layer
to be a linear layer, i.e., the output is just the result of the convolution
without the non-linearity $z^l_{...}$. This is not relevant since it does not
influence the dimensionality of the operations. The convolution operations are
one-based index.

Furthermore, we will consider that the error at the output of the convolutional
layer is known, so
there is no need to consider any other layer. Further, to unclutter notation,
we will consider one instance batches and we will omit the batch dimension. Finally, we will assume padding zero and stride one (sorry, but otherwise, it becomes way too complicated).

Now, we have:

1. $l$ is the $l$th layer where $l=1$ is the first layer and $l=\ell$ is the last layer.
2. The Input tensor $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{X}} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 
           n \times 
           n}$ with dimensions width $w$, height $h$ and three channels $c$.
3. The Kernel tensor $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{K}} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 
           n \times 
           n \times n}$ with dimensions width $m$, height $n$, three channels $c$,
   and $k$
   kernels that will produce $k$ feature maps.
4. Every kernel $k$ in $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{K}}_{:,:,:,k}$ has weights
   $w_{...}$.
5. The derivative of the loss function $J$ w.r.t. an input activation
   $z^l_{x,y,z}$, say, is defined as

   \begin{equation}
       \delta^l_{x,y,z} = \frac{\partial J}{\partial \; z^l_{x,y,z}}
   \end{equation}

First, we need to restate the equations in the corresponding form:

The 3D convolution acts such as one element of the output
$\mathsf{M}{\,}^{l}_{i,j,k}$ is the scalar resulting from multiplying and
adding the corresponding elements of the input with one kernel which weights
are
$w^l_{m,n,c,k}$. I.e.,

\begin{align}
{\big( (\boldsymbol{\mathsf{I}} * \boldsymbol{\mathsf{K}})(i,j,k) 
    \big)}^l 
&= \sum_{c} 
\sum_{m} \sum_{n} x^{l - 1}_{i + m - 1,j + n - 1,c} \cdot w^l_{m,n,c,k} 
\label{eq:cross_correlation_3d_1}\\
z^l_{i,j,k} &= {\big( (\boldsymbol{\mathsf{I}} * 
    \boldsymbol{\mathsf{K}})(i,j,k) \big)}^l + b^l\\
\mathsf{M}{\,}^{l}_{i,j,k} &= 
z^l_{i,j,k}.\label{eq:cross_correlation_3d_3}
\end{align}

Here $i,j,k$ are the output iterators.

The strategy we will follow is the one explained by Nielsen with some priority
changes, i.e., first we will derive the backpropagation rule
($\delta^l_{\cdot,\cdot,\cdot}$ in term of $\delta^{l + 
1}_{\cdot,\cdot,\cdot}$).
Second, derive the error of the weights (derivative of the loss w.r.t. the
kernel weights) in terms of $\delta^{l + 1}_{\cdot,\cdot,\cdot}$.

The 2D case derivation suggests that, in the end, we will have some kind of
convolution of the layer error with the kernels.

Let us start with the error of one element at layer $\delta^l_{m,n,u}$ w.r.t.
to the error at layer $\delta^{l + 1}_{i,j,k}$. In order to apply the chain
rule, we
have to identify which output elements $z^{l + 1}_{i,j,k}$ are affected by the
input element
$z^l_{m,n,u}$, so that we can add the partial derivatives. One important
observation is that one input element affects all feature maps (albeit not all
elements), so we must sum over all output channels $k$. Another (trivial?)
observation is that the multi-channel $\boldsymbol{\mathsf{K}}$ does not move
across the depth dimension,
therefore the index does not contain offsets. After having considered the
channels, we must further consider the effect of the input element
$z^l_{m,n,u}$ in one
specific output channel $z^l_{:,:,k}$. Using the 2D analogy, we can say that
given a
specific
channels $k$, the input element affects some elements in that channel, namely
the
elements fixed at the position $m,n$, and that are the results of the kernel
having been slit by by $-a, -b$ (input perspective, we introduce auxiliary
indices $a$ and $b$). Finally, we know that all
kernels have the same dimensionality (they are packed in one 4D-tensor), thus,
we can use the same iterators $a,b$ for all kernels. These observations lead to

\begin{align}
\delta^l_{m,n,u} &= \sum_{k} \sum_a \sum_b \frac{\partial 
    J}{\partial \; z^{l + 
        1}_{m - a + 1,n - b + 1,k}} 
\cdot \frac{\partial z^{l + 1}_{m - a + 1,n - b + 1,k}}{\partial 
    z^l_{m,n,u}}\label{eq:delta1}\tag{1}\\
&= \sum_{k} \sum_a \sum_b \delta^{l + 
    1}_{m - a + 1,n - b + 1,k} 
\cdot \frac{\partial z^{l + 1}_{m - a + 1,n - b + 1,k}}{\partial 
    z^l_{m,n,u}}.\label{eq:delta2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

That was one of the most difficult steps, where I could have committed errors.
Feel free to correct me.

Here, we substituted, as usual, the error $\frac{\partial 
J}{\partial \; z^{l + 1}_{m - a + 1,n - b + 1,k}}$  by its definition
$\delta^{l + 
1}_{m - a + 1,n - b + 1,k}$.

You know where this is heading.

We now focus on the second term on the right and expand it. Here, again we
introduce auxiliary indices $p, q, r$, and use $x^l_{...} = z^l_{...}$ (as
mentioned, we deal with linear layers).

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial z^{l + 1}_{m - a + 1,n - b + 1,k}}{\partial z^l_{m,n,u}} &= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial z^l_{m,n,u}} \Big( 
\sum_{p} \sum_{q} \sum_{r} z^{l}_{(m - a + 1) + p - 1,(n - b + 1) + q - 1,r} 
\cdot w^{l + 
    1}_{p,q,r,k}\Big)\label{eq1}\tag{3}\\
&= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial z^l_{m,n,u}} \Big( 
\sum_{p} \sum_{q} \sum_{r} z^{l}_{m - a + p,n - b + q,r} 
\cdot w^{l + 1}_{p,q,r,k}\Big)\label{eq2}\tag{4}\\
&= 
\frac{\partial}{\partial z^l_{m,n,u}} \Big( z^{l}_{m,n,u} 
\cdot w^{l + 1}_{a,b,u,k}\Big)\label{eq3}\tag{5}\\
&= w^{l + 1}_{a,b,u,k}.\label{eq4}\tag{6}
\end{align}

In Eq. \ref{eq1} we expanded as mentioned above, then in Eq. \ref{eq2} we
reduced the indices as $(m - a + 1) + p - 1 = m - a + p, (n - b + 1) + q - 1 = 
n - b + q$. In Eq. \ref{eq3} we observe that all partial derivatives w.r.t.
$z^l_{m,n,u}$, except when $a = p, b = q, r = u$. Accordingly, the weights must
have indices $a,b,u,k$. Then, plugging Eq. \ref{eq4} in Eq.\ref{eq:delta2}, we
have:

\begin{align}
\delta^l_{m,n,u} &= \sum_{k} \sum_a \sum_b \delta^{l + 
    1}_{m - a + 1,n - b + 1,k} 
\cdot w^{l + 1}_{a,b,u,k}.\label{eq:final1}\tag{7}
\end{align}

The second most difficult part is how to interpret Eq.\ref{eq:final1}. As
mentioned above, it is clear that this is *some kind* of convolution between
the error at the end of the convolutional layer (the error it receives from the
*upper* layer) with the kernel tensor. One thing we can do is transform
(rotate?) the kernel to rearrange the indices, i.e.,

\begin{align}
\delta^l_{m,n,u} &= \sum_{k} \sum_a \sum_b \delta^{l + 
    1}_{m - a + 1,n - b + 1,k} 
\cdot w^{l + 1}_{a,b,k,u}.\label{eq:final2}\tag{8}
\end{align}

In Eq.\ref{eq:final2}, we can see that we have to collect all partial
derivatives corresponding to elements in all channels $k$ having been generated
by channel $u$. This is somehow not intuitive and difficult to picture (at
least for me) because
all input channels are combined/merged to create a feature map. So, how can we
*untangle* a feature map to collect specific the input elements of one channel
that were *melted* to form the feature map? It turns out that one can if you
think in *algebraic* terms. The output is a tensor, and therefore, provided one
has the right indices, the operation can be conducted. This *standard* 3D
convolution may surely be expressed as a 3D cross-correlation. Ideas are
welcome.

An interesting concrete example is given by [Aggarwal 2018](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-94463-0) on page 355:

> In order to understand the transposition above, consider a situation
> in which  we use 20 filters on the 3-channel RGB volume in order to
> create an output volume of  depth 20. While backpropagating, we will
> need to take a gradient volume of depth 20 and  transform to a
> gradient volume of depth 3. Therefore, we need to create 3 filters for
> backpropagation, each of which is for the red, green, and blue colors.
> We pull out the 20  spatial slices from the 20 filters that are
> applied to the red color invert them using the  the approach of Figure
> 8.7, and then create a single 20-depth filter for backpropagating gradients with  respect to the red slice. Similar approaches are used
> for the green and blue slices. The  transposition and inversion in
> Equation 8.3 corresponds to these operations.

The derivation of the derivatives of the cost function w.r.t. the kernel
weights and bias are left as exercise ;)